# can you use split_cols_by and also get a total column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm making a table like this:

```
basic_table() %>%
  split_cols_by("ARM") %>%
  analyze(vars = c("AGE", "BMRKR1"), afun = function(x) {
    in_rows(
      "Mean (sd)" = rcell(c(mean(x), sd(x)), format = "xx.xx (xx.xx)"),
      "Range" = rcell(range(x), format = "xx.xx - xx.xx")
    )
  }) %>%
  build_table(ADSL)
```

with looks like this

```
               A: Drug X      B: Placebo    C: Combination
----------------------------------------------------------
AGE                                                       
  Mean (sd)   33.77 (6.55)   35.43 (7.9)     35.43 (7.72) 
  Range         21 - 50        21 - 62         20 - 69    
BMRKR1                                                    
  Mean (sd)   5.97 (3.55)     5.7 (3.31)     5.62 (3.49)  
  Range       0.41 - 17.67   0.65 - 14.24    0.17 - 21.39
```

(see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtables/vignettes/clinical_trials.html)

I would like to get an additional column, which includes all the data - is that possible?

Comment: What data? Can you share the desired output? Have you tried some other approach not dependent on this particular package?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
split_cols_by("ARM", split_fun=add_overall_level("All", first=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

The vignette at:

https://rdrr.io/cran/rtables/f/vignettes/split_functions.Rmd

gives a clear example of knokknok's answer and of

```
split_cols_by("color", split_fun = add_combo_levels(combodf))
```

which allows totaling up subsets of columns specified in combodf.

In the spirit of giving a complete answer as pointed out in the comments:

```
library(rtables)
ADSL <- ex_adsl
basic_table() %>%
  split_cols_by("ARM", split_fun=add_overall_level("All", first=FALSE)) %>%
  analyze(vars = c("AGE", "BMRKR1"), afun = function(x) {
    in_rows(
      "Mean (sd)" = rcell(c(mean(x), sd(x)), format = "xx.xx (xx.xx)"),
      "Range" = rcell(range(x), format = "xx.xx - xx.xx")
    )
  }) %>%
  build_table(ADSL)
```

Which yields:

```
                A: Drug X      B: Placebo     C: Combination        All     
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
AGE                                                                         
  Mean (sd)   33.77 (6.55)    35.43 (7.90)     35.43 (7.72)    34.88 (7.44) 
  Range       21.00 - 50.00   21.00 - 62.00   20.00 - 69.00    20.00 - 69.00
BMRKR1                                                                      
  Mean (sd)    5.97 (3.55)     5.70 (3.31)     5.62 (3.49)      5.76 (3.45) 
  Range       0.41 - 17.67    0.65 - 14.24     0.17 - 21.39    0.17 - 21.39 
>
```